# magento not sending out contact us email, no error displayed

Tags: php, email, magento, contact-form

i m using magento for the first time. I m just putting the contact us form present in the site, into my footer block. The form is getting submitted but no errors are displayed. I m not recieving any emails from that form.

I have made the necessary settings

Enable Contact Us : yes

Send Emails To : myemail.

But still no luck.. pls guide me to the solution and where things are goin wrong

Comment: If you have logging enabled on admin panel under `System/Configuration/Advanced/Developer/Log settings`, check the `var/log/exception.log` file in yoour magento root. Magento will catch and hide the error, but write it to this file if the error happens in the mail sending. (so your site will not break because of a backgound process)

Comment: ya its working now.. i freshly created a my page and now i m running my mails thru php mail function.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on localhost?If yes you need an SMTP server to listen port no 25 to be able to send email.